# Typescript create a type with required keys from another type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following `type` defined:

```
export type colors = "red" | "blue" | "green"

export interface details {
   name: string;
   id: string;
}
```

Is there a way to define a `type` object that **requires** all 3 to be defined, without having to loop through each explicitly?

```
export interface allColors {
   red: details;
   blue: details;
   ... etc.
}
```

as opposed to this `type` which makes the keys optional?

```
export type allColors =  {
    [key in colors]: details;
};
```

Comment: Didn't get it. interface allColors is the same as type allColors.

Comment: @qxg the type doesn't require all of those properties, whereas the `interface` would require all of them to be set.

Comment: It works as expected for me (v3.9.2): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAxg9gGzgJwM5QLxQETIgE2ygB8cAjBAVwiNOwHM8IA7bAbgFgAoAS2eAjIAZgEMY0fBGAieCdAG9uUKMxEBbCAC4oqYMj71OXZT3zbd+5oe4Bfbt1CQoIhAgDCiFOixRFxqADaANYQIFB8sJ5oALraktKyqEZ2XNzwzLqw2i7uUd6+SlB4ZgX+yqoa2gDkxVUANIUmJVUAxEJCAAxdHfWFKSlAA

Comment: @Soc is right. This works as expected. Make sure you have `"strict": true` in tsconfig.json compilerOptions and are running a relatively recent version of TypeScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) and [Record type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt).

```
export type colors = "red" | "blue" | "green"

export interface details {
   name: string;
   id: string;
}

export type allColors = Record<colors, details> 

// Usage
const x: allColors = { // type error, missing properties: 'blue', 'green'
  red: {
    name: 'red',
    id: '1'
  }
}
```

Suppose you want to override the type of certain keys, say you want `green: number` instead of `green: details`, you can achieve this using [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) and [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
export type allColors = Record<Exclude<colors, 'green'>, details> & {green: string}

// Usage
const x: allColors = { 
  red: {
    name: 'red',
    id: '1'
  },
  green: 'hello' // No error
}
```